# telerik radgrid-pagination issue

Tags: c#-3.0, telerik

Why is pagination not working in my radgrid? If I click the pages (numbers) or next/previous buttons I can see only a single line, not even a grid.

Please help!

Comment: If you add some code then we might be able to help and please remember to use the code tags if you do.

Answer (score 1):

This can happ[en if you use binding with DataBind() calls and does not handle paging and sorting manually as with MS GridView. There is a quick fix though - hook the NeedDataSource event of the Telerik grid as shown here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/needdatasource/defaultcs.aspx).